# Glide not reload the images from server

Tags: android-glide

I have a recyclerview that displays photos.

this is my adapter:

```
public class CustomerImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerImageListAdapter.Holder> {
private Context context;
private List<String> imageUrls;

public CustomerImageListAdapter(Context context, List<String> imageUrls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customer_onitemclick_image_viewpager_item, parent, false);

    return new Holder(rootview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrls.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);

    if (imageUrls.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("urls", "onBindViewHolder: " + imageUrls.get(i));
        }
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageUrls.size();
}

class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_onitemclick_image_viewpager_item_imageview);
    }
}

public void setImageUrls(List<String> imageUrls1) {
    imageUrls.addAll(imageUrls1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

when i set the "imageurls" in the constructor, recyclerview show the images perfectly;

```
imageListAdapter = new CustomerImageListAdapter(getContext(),urls);
```

but when i set in constructor "new ArrayList()" and use "setImagesUrls" method to update "imageurls",
then recyclerview don't show images .

```
imageListAdapter = new CustomerImageListAdapter(getContext(),new ArrayList<String>());

 ...
  ...
 ...

 @Override{
        public void onChanged(List<String> strings) 

            imageListAdapter.setImageUrls(strings);

        }
```

While based on the "log" ,address of  the images are received from the server.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position)
     {
     Glide.with(context).load(imageUrls.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);

     if (imageUrls.size() != 0) {
     for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("urls", "onBindViewHolder: " + imageUrls.get(i));
     }
}
```

}

thanks for your help